# Crear fichero y manipularlo con RandomAccessFile

Tags: java

Qué tal todo? Espero que vaya bien el confinamiento. Es la primera vez que escribo, ya que llevo poco tiempo en Java. Os cuento:

Estoy practicando con RandomAccessFile y alguno de sus métodos. He pensado en lo siguiente, utilizar 2 clases:
1º la clase archivo_funciones, es donde creo el fichero y hago cada método para luego llamarlo en la 2º clase que es main con un menu.

Tengo que rellenar una sala de cine, con int-> num de asiento, boolean-> si está ocupado o no, string-> nombre y string-> dni. Sé que esto va por un determinado fijo de bytes para cada registro.
La idea es mostrar por consola todos los asientos enumerados, vacios, con datos a null.
Posteriormente empezar a llenar la sala, pidiendo el asiento o diciendo cuales están vacios para guardar el registro.
Y finalmente mostrar los asientos ocupados con los datos de las personas.

Tengo lo siguiente

```
public class Archivo_funciones {

    static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner entradaInt = new Scanner(System.in);

    int asiento;                // tiene 4 bytes
    String dni = " ";                 // tiene 10 bytes 
    String nombre = " ";              // tiene 30 bytes + 2 UTF
    boolean ocupado = false;    // tiene 1 byte
    //tamaño total de cada registro 47  

    File archivo;
    RandomAccessFile raf;
    final int tamano_registro = 47;

    public Archivo_funciones() {
        archivo = new File("cine.txt");
    }

    // creo el fichero
    public void crear_fichero() {

        try {

            raf = new RandomAccessFile(archivo, "rw");

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {          // el total de asiento será 50
                raf.seek(i * tamano_registro);
                asiento = i + 1;
                raf.writeInt(asiento);              // el numero del asiento

                raf.seek(i * tamano_registro + 4);  // es para decirle si esta libre o no, en principio estará vacio todo a false.
                raf.writeBoolean(false);

                raf.seek(i * tamano_registro + 5);  // nombre
                raf.writeUTF(nombre);

                raf.seek(i * tamano_registro + 37); //dni
                raf.writeUTF(dni);
            }

            raf.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }

    // en principio debe de mostrar los asientos vacios sin nombre y dni
    public void ver_registros() {

        try {
            raf = new RandomAccessFile(archivo, "r");

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                System.out.println("Asiento: " + (i + 1) + " Se encuentra " + ocupado + " Persona: " + nombre + " DNI: " + dni);
            }

            raf.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }

    // luego pasará a agregar una persona
    public void agregar_persona() {
        boolean esta_ocupado = false;

        try {

            raf = new RandomAccessFile(archivo, "rw");

            System.out.println("ingrese num de asiento: ");
            int num_asiento = entradaInt.nextInt();     // le pido el asiento
            raf.seek(num_asiento * tamano_registro);
            raf.writeBoolean(true);                     // cuando termina de ingresar a la persona, pasa de false a true

            System.out.println("ingrese nombre: ");
            String nombre_persona = entrada.nextLine();
            raf.seek(num_asiento * tamano_registro + 5);
            raf.writeUTF(nombre);                       // escribe el nombre

            System.out.println("ingrese dni: ");
            String dni_persona = entrada.nextLine();
            raf.seek(num_asiento * tamano_registro + 37);
            raf.writeUTF(dni);                          // y dni

            raf.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }

    // y aqui es donde me muestra los asientos ocupado
    public void ver_personas() {

        try {

            raf = new RandomAccessFile(archivo, "r");

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                raf.seek(i * tamano_registro);
                asiento = i+1;
                raf.readInt();

                raf.seek(i * tamano_registro + 4);
                raf.readBoolean();

                raf.seek(i * tamano_registro + 5);
                raf.readUTF();

                raf.seek(i * tamano_registro + 37);
                raf.readUTF();

                System.out.println("Asiento: " +asiento+ " " +ocupado+ " " +nombre+ " " +dni);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }

}
```

Aunque guarde una nueva persona, cuando llamo al método de ver_personas no me aparece las que he guardado.

Gracias por los consejos y feliz domingo!.